YA novel with dual perspectives and amnesia/memory loss
I'm looking for a book published around 2009-2012, its a young adult novel with both the girl and boy perspectives. The girl is popular, the boy is not. They are both suffering from gaps in their memories. They both were together, and remember being together, but their relationship was hidden and nobody around them knows they were together. The girl is living in an abusive situation, and tries to escape their town on the bus to pursue her dream of becoming an actress but for some reason, she cannot.
I remember a distinct scene where the girl needs scissors, and asks everyone in the girls locker room. All the girls scramble to find her scissors, and she is surprised as she does not remember she is popular. Also, the boy character is a nerd that is in a tech club
There is also some sort of villain, an older man that prevents her from escaping. There is some mind control drug that is involved. If I remember correctly, the girl is an unwilling participant in the villain's experiment, she gets her memory wiped more than once, and the boy somehow also gets his memory wiped due to his contact with the girl.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This sounds like it's only maybe borderline on-topic.  Is there any actual SF element, or is it more of a thriller?

If I remember correctly, the girl is an unwilling participant in the villian's experiment, she gets her memory wiped more than once, and the boy somehow also gets his memory wiped due to his contact with the girl
